# Error when installing JVCL on Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, dependencies, delphi-7, jvcl

On installing jvcl I have the following error message:
'No delphi/BCB/BDS/Rad-studio versions was found that has the required depdendencies installed.
please install the dependencies first.'
What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: As the error messaged suggests, you might be missing some dependencies that JVCL requires. I don't know what installer you used, but it could be that you might be missing JCL.

Comment: YEs, there is also JCL library with JVCL in install pack. But  didn't know that I should install JCL first. Actually I also tried to install JCL,but had some another error during installation.

Comment: What error did you get when installing JCL?

Comment: Error when compiling on the picture above. Should I delete that JCLProjectAnalysis package from JCL install folder or download new JCL install?

Comment: Unfortunately the 'compiling' window is on top of the installation log. I can't read the full message, but what is the compiler error message that is thrown?  Just not installing the package might be a workaround, but it's not the solution for the problem.

Comment: The error is "could not compile used unit JclProjectAnalyzerFrm.pas". Of course there are some error in this file. But I didn't want to search them ,so I did as You suggest,uncheked "IDE experts" when installing.Now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states that not all dependencies are installed. It turned out that JCL was not properly installed before JVCL was installed.